# C# arranging string variables in some container

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am new to C# i have these many string values in my code as

```
string text1 = textbox1.text;
string text2 = textbox2.text;
string text3 = textbox3.text;
string text4 = textbox4.text;
```

and some bool values as well

```
bool chk1 = checkBox1.Checked;
bool chk2 = checkBox2.Checked;
bool chk3 = checkBox3.Checked;
```

also i have checkboxes types to be true

```
checkBox2.Checked = true;
checkBox3.Checked = true;
checkBox4.Checked = true;
checkBox5.Checked = true;
```

the checkbox part is basically at form load
Is there a way to write some neat code and reduce no. of lines?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using WPF, you can use data binding to reduce this sort of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrays:

```
string[] texts = { textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text, textbox4.Text };

bool[] checks = { checkBox1.Checked, checkBox2.Checked, checkBox3.Checked };
```

Comment: and the access would be doe as bool[1] chk;

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to understand your context here. What are these strings?
Since it's repetitive the only thing off my mind would be to use arrays, for less lines of code.

Comment: these are values from the text fields

Answer (score 0):

```
var texts = { textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text, textbox4.Text };
var checks = { checkBox1.Checked, checkBox2.Checked, checkBox3.Checked };
```

It's also will be good to have special arrays for textboxes and checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings and bools are created everytime in a fix number, I would tend to use `Arrays`.

```
string[] texts = { textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, textbox3.Text, textbox4.Text };

bool[] checks = { checkBox1.Checked, checkBox2.Checked, checkBox3.Checked };
```

If not, I would use `List<string> and List<bool>`, there you can add and delete your values.

```
List<string> myTexts = new List<string>();
myTexts.Add(textbox1.Text);
```

You can access the values in the same way like you do in Arrays:

```
Console.Write(myTexts[0]);
```

You can also think about using a class with properties to manage the variables:

```
class myValues
{
   internal string text1 { get; set; }
   internal string text2 { get; set; }
   internal string text3 { get; set; }
   internal string text4 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: (just change the type of the control you want)

```
        List<String> TextList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in Controls)
        {
            if (item is TextBox)
            {
                TextList.Add(((TextBox)item).Text);
            }
        }
```